# Set background picture of body to user inputed URL w/ Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I am currently trying to change the background image to an image submitted by the user (for fun), but I'm having a hard time. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: use the file reader API http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Comment: or do you mean somebody enters a url of an image into a input type text and you then take that url and and change the background image on your body tag - that would be easier but either way it can be done

Answer (score 0):

With .css or .attr and etc., you can easily alter anything you could with CSS with jquery. Put it in an onClick() js function or however it's being triggered.

```
$("body").css("background-image", "url(/image.png)"); 
//Note that if you are altering a div it will have to be #divID or .divClass and not just untagged like body is
```

Comment: I think he wants to use the image provided by the user like a file upload which can only be accomplished using html 5 file reader api

Comment: Ahh I misunderstood, sorry. So without actually having the website host it?

Comment: right unless he meant a different user input input in which you could just store the val var value = $('input').val(); and then do something like you said $("body").css("background-image", value); e.g somebody entered in a url they got from a google image search

Comment: Yes James, that's what I was hoping for.